# Working of S3 file download

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0

To download a file from S3 using java SDK, we need to do the following ->
Note- Multipart download is off.

```
S3Object s3Object = s3.getObject(getObjectRequest);
S3ObjectInputStream s3ObjectInputStream = s3Object.getObjectContent();
//Write to a file from this stream
```

When we make a getObject call, the SDK does a GET call on that object.
This call returns just the headers of the response.

When we actually start reading from the s3ObjectInputStream, we get the response body.
But this all is one REST call.

So, I was confused why the call returned only the headers first.
And how did S3 know when to start sending in the response body?

We are making only one call, so how are we notifying S3 that we have now started reading from the s3ObjectInputStream.
Where is the actual file stored till we read it from the stream ?

Answer (score 0):

S3 starts sending the response body immediately.

You just haven't started reading it from the network.

> `getObject`
>
> Be extremely careful when using this method; the returned Amazon S3 object contains a direct stream of data from the HTTP connection. The underlying HTTP connection cannot be reused until the user finishes reading the data and closes the stream.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#getObject-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest-

A small amount has been buffered, but the object isn't being stored anywhere.  The network connection is stalled. 
 If you were to start a request and wait long enough before reading it, S3 would eventually detect the connection as stalled, give up, and close the connection.

In practice, it's easy to separate HTTP headers from body in a stream, because the boundary between them is always exactly `\r\n\r\n`.  This 4 byte sequence is invalid within the headers, and mandatory after the headers, so the SDK simply stops extracting headers at this point in the response from S3 and builds and returns the response object, from which you can read the body from the stream from the network.

Comment: Then what is the best way to download a big file without mulipart download?

And what exactly happens when we start reading from the stream ?

Where is the data till that time ? Is it in the socket  buffer or still in S3 servers ?